# How do I get rid of the Skype lady?

Tags: skype, binary-files

For what feels like a year, Skype has had a picture of this lady in the middle of the interface.

[image: Skype Lady]

No offense to the lady, but seeing her face in the middle of my contacts is distracting. When I look at Skype I want to see my contacts, not an unfocused picture of a lady adjusting her webcam in her stainless steel kitchen.

**What I've Tried**

- Updating Skype
- Extracting resources from Skype.exe using NirSoft's ResourcesExtract (the picture is not stored there as a plain image).
- Studying `AppData\Roaming\Skype`
- Writing this question.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Take a look: https://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/How-do-I-remove-this-girl-s-face/td-p/4080110

Comment: she looks *eerily* like someone I used to know.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Yeah, I know.

Comment: @duDE When I look at the link you give I find complicated instructions for doing what OP asks, together with a note saying they do not work. Do you find an answer that does work?

Comment: @ColinMcLarty I think meanwhile OP has found the answer that works. Hope the link has helped.

Answer (score 5):

IN View drop down select default page as call or profile rather than home than will do the trick.

Comment: Nice trick, +1. Wasn't aware of that option, I like that -- the Call page seems more practical than the default.

Answer (score 1):

After some more research, here are two possible methods found on the Skype forum. Not sure if either will work long-term. If you have other ideas, please post an answer.

**Method 1: toggling the view**

In the main window, perform these two actions:

- View / Split Window View
- View / Single Window View

**Method 2: custom language file**

- Tools / Change Language / Edit Language File
- Press "Save As" and select a folder you can write to
- Tools / Change Language / Load Language File / load the file you saved

You may have to restart skype (for a full quit, right-click the tray icon and select "quit")

**Bonus: Disabling Skype Updates**

In addition to these methods, it may be useful to disable Skype updates, both to get rid of the annoying window and to avoid things getting mangled again.

Two methods to disable Skype update:

**A. Disable using AutoHotkey.** If you already use AutoHotkey, you can do something like the following (to be refined) to kill the "Update available" window that pops up even when you've turned off auto-updates:

```
Loop 
{ 
WinWait, Update
WinClose, Update
}
```

**B. Disable in hosts file.** If you don't use AutoHotkey, use the following to kill updates:

- Disable updates in Skype (Tools / Options / Advanced / Automatic Updates)
- Add download.skype.com to your hosts file: `127.0.0.1   download.skype.com  # disable skype updates`
- On Windows, disable the Skype updater service
- On Windows, delete Skype-related files from the `%TEMP%` folder

**References**

- [How do I remove this girls face?](https://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/How-do-I-remove-this-girl-s-face/td-p/4080110)
- [Totally stop Skype updates](https://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Total-Stop-Skype-update/td-p/1999473)

Comment: Method 2 totally worked. I still get an AdChoices ad, but the lady is gone! It worked for a coworker of mine too. For sure works with version 7.40.0.151